# Why this vba formula does not change the value of the sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to inquire about the vba code I created below. After I test it turns the sheet value unchanged. How to fix this code so that when the value I input can be updated in the *sheet*?

```
Private Sub cmdupdate_click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim noM As Integer
'warning
    If txtName.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Insert Name.", vbExclamation
        txtName.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

If Me.cmbslno.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "No Number!!!", vbExclamation, "Number"
Exit Sub
End If
noM = Me.cmbslno.Value
Sheets("data").Select
Dim bre As Double
Dim msg As String
Dim org As String
bre = Me.cmbslno.Value
bre = bre + 1
Rows(bre).Select
Cells(bre, 2) = Me.txtName.Value
Cells(bre, 3) = Me.txtPanggilan.Value
Cells(bre, 4) = Me.txtNis.Value
Cells(bre, 5) = Me.txtNisn.Value
Cells(bre, 6) = Me.txtTtl.Value
Cells(bre, 7) = Me.CmbJk.Value
Cells(bre, 8) = Me.CmbAgama.Value
Cells(bre, 9) = Me.txtSAwal.Value
Cells(bre, 10) = Me.txtASiswa.Value
Cells(bre, 11) = Me.txtAyah.Value
Cells(bre, 12) = Me.txtIbu.Value
Cells(bre, 13) = Me.txtPAyah.Value
Cells(bre, 14) = Me.txtPIbu.Value
Cells(bre, 15) = Me.txtJln.Value
Cells(bre, 16) = Me.txtDesa.Value
Cells(bre, 17) = Me.txtKec.Value
Cells(bre, 18) = Me.txtKab.Value
Cells(bre, 19) = Me.txtPro.Value
Cells(bre, 20) = Me.txtHp.Value
Cells(bre, 21) = Me.txtWali.Value
Cells(bre, 22) = Me.txtPWali.Value
Cells(bre, 23) = Me.txtAWali.Value
Cells(bre, 36) = Me.txtFoto.Value
bre = bre - 1
msg = "Number " & bre & ". For " & txtName.Value & "  Updating . Continue?"
Unload Me
org = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Confirm")
If org = vbYes Then
Me.FormData.Show
Else
Sheets("Data").Select
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you, hope it can be resolved

Comment: Can you indent your code please.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint inside to test if it actually run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see your updated code. I think the problem was in missing `.Value` property in cell value assignment statements. I also corrected some other minor issues, please see the comments.

```vb
Private Sub cmdupdate_click()

    'warning
    If Me.txtName.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please insert name.", vbExclamation
        Me.txtName.SetFocus  'added Me for consistency
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.cmbslno.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter number.", vbExclamation 'stopped yelling at the user
        Me.cmbslno.SetFocus  ' added - the same behaviour as previous one
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'moved here, otherwise above Exit Sub  keeps False
    Dim noM As Integer 'moved from top, we don't need it earlier
    noM = Val(Me.cmbslno.Value)
    Sheets("data").Select
    Dim bre As Integer  ' changed from Double to Integer
    Dim msg As String
    Dim org As String
    bre = Me.cmbslno.Value
    bre = noM + 1
    Rows(bre).Select
    Cells(bre, 2).Value = Me.txtName.Value
    Cells(bre, 3).Value = Me.txtPanggilan.Value
    Cells(bre, 4).Value = Me.txtNis.Value
    Cells(bre, 5).Value = Me.txtNisn.Value
    Cells(bre, 6).Value = Me.txtTtl.Value
    Cells(bre, 7).Value = Me.CmbJk.Value
    Cells(bre, 8).Value = Me.CmbAgama.Value
    Cells(bre, 9).Value = Me.txtSAwal.Value
    Cells(bre, 10).Value = Me.txtASiswa.Value
    Cells(bre, 11).Value = Me.txtAyah.Value
    Cells(bre, 12).Value = Me.txtIbu.Value
    Cells(bre, 13).Value = Me.txtPAyah.Value
    Cells(bre, 14).Value = Me.txtPIbu.Value
    Cells(bre, 15).Value = Me.txtJln.Value
    Cells(bre, 16).Value = Me.txtDesa.Value
    Cells(bre, 17).Value = Me.txtKec.Value
    Cells(bre, 18).Value = Me.txtKab.Value
    Cells(bre, 19).Value = Me.txtPro.Value
    Cells(bre, 20).Value = Me.txtHp.Value
    Cells(bre, 21).Value = Me.txtWali.Value
    Cells(bre, 22).Value = Me.txtPWali.Value
    Cells(bre, 23).Value = Me.txtAWali.Value
    Cells(bre, 36).Value = Me.txtFoto.Value

    msg = "Number " & noM & ". For " & txtName.Value & "  Updating. Continue?"
    Unload Me
    org = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Confirm")
    If org = vbYes Then
        Me.FormData.Show
    Else
        Sheets("Data").Select
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```